# Changing R script from a time range between 8 and 6 to 24 hours (everything)

Tags: r, timestamp

I have to use a code for some work I'm doing which works perfectly. However to make this faster previously we have selected only the time range needed from each bin file and on this occcasion I need a full day. My knowledge with POSIXct is limited, I hoped it would be as simple as selecting from hour 0 - 24, so clearly out of my depth.

I'd appreciate any help and ideally I only want to change this one section because its a lengthy script and this all that needs editing.

***#read in data for that day between 8am and 6pm***

`Starttime = as.numeric(as.POSIXct(Day, format="%d/%m/%Y")) + 8*60*60`

`Endtime = Starttime + 10*60*60`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand the question, something like this?

```
Day <- format(Sys.Date(), "%d/%m/%Y")    # test date
Day <- as.POSIXct(Day, format = "%d/%m/%Y")

Starttime <- Day + lubridate::hours(8)
Starttime
#[1] "2020-09-13 08:00:00 WEST"

Day + lubridate::days(1) - lubridate::seconds(1)
#[1] "2020-09-13 23:59:59 WEST"
```

If functions from package `lubridate` are to be used more often, load the package. It has equivalent functions for many other periods, from `picoseconds` up to `years`.

The examples in the question of 8 and 10 hours could be like below.
The results can be coerced to class `"numeric"` if needed.

```
library(lubridate)

as.numeric(Starttime)
#[1] 1599980400
as.numeric(Day + hours(8))  # the same as above
#[1] 1599980400

Endtime <- Starttime + hours(10)
Endtime
#[1] "2020-09-13 18:00:00 WEST"

as.numeric(Day + days(1) - seconds(1))
#[1] 1600037999
```

Comment: Thank you for speedy reply, I didn't articulate myself well. I have above code currently as we only look at the bin files between that time range of 8 - 6pm, I however don't want to be restricted by this time and want to modify these lines to include everything... so I get all 24 hours of data for all 26 days

Comment: @DestinyLBradley Then you can subset the data with logical conditions, say, `i <- date >= Starttime & date < Endtime`, where `date` is the data file date column. Without an example data set it's difficult to say.

Comment: I would send examples but I cant in an open form really:( thank you for your help though